# Bash script not recognizing root directory on remote server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am working on a remote Linux server, connected using SSH. I am new to Unix.

My repo is stored in `root/data/anj/myrepo`. Now my home directory `root/home/anj/` contains a bash file which executes the code stored in myrepo. But when I run the bash file, it doesn't seem to recognize the root directory and reach the repo. I get the output "file not found" when it tries to execute a file in my repo. How do I get the bash script to recognize the path from the root directory to the repo? It seems that the file is interpreting `/data/anj/myrepo` as `root/home/anj/data/anj/myrepo`, which shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a / in front of root, because if you don't do that then you are looking for a relative path, but i guess you are looking for the absolute path. so try /root/data/anj/myrepo instead of root/data/anj/myrepo :D

Good luck!